# I need to read this package d3a https://github.com/gridsingularity/d3a

Tags: python, docker, package

I want to install this package, i tried to run it through

> > **pip install d3a**

but i couldn't, there is a docker file but i couldn't install it through the docker file as well.

Comment: Which Operating System?

Comment: It is windows 7

Comment: See https://github.com/gridsingularity/d3a#basic-setup

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i do installed the fabric then i can't understand the solidity part, i dived through the website but still can't get its idea.

Comment: Since you are a windows user, see https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.1/installing-solidity.html#prerequisites-windows

Comment: Yes i downloaded these softwares but when i run fab sync i got fatal error message